# Code to numerically integrate a system of first-order ODEs

Tags: matlab, ode

I need to solve the following system of differential equations. 
[image]

When I have the solutions for $n_f$ and $v$, I need to find and plot $J=-e_\cdot n_{f} \cdot v$.

I wrote a code in matlab with all ODEs like this:

```
      function systemSolve
      clc


      tr=50e-12;        % Recombination lifetime
      n0=1e11;         % Density of free carriers (Recordar que es 1e17 cm-3)
      tc=2e-12;         % Trapping time
      ts=30e-15;        % Carrier scattering time
      m=0.067*9.11e-31; % effective mass GaAs
      ev=8.854e-12;     % permitivity  
      n=900;            % factor geometry
      q=1.6e-19         % electron charge

      de=50e-15         %  delta t


      timeRange=[0 0.1e-12]; 
      initialConditionVector=[0;1e-15;1e-15;1e-15];
      [t,x]=ode45(@xprime,timeRange,initialConditionVector);
      figure(1),plot(t,x(:,1))

      J=q*x(:,3).*x(:,1);
      figure(2),plot(t,J)

      function f=xprime(t,x)
      f=[x(4); ...
        -(x(2)/tr)+(x(3)*q*x(1)); ...
        -(x(3)/tc)+(n0*(exp((t/de)^2))); ...
        -((1/ts)*x(4))-(((x(3)*q^2)/m*ev)*x(1)/n)+(q*x(2)/(m*n*ev*tr))];
      end
end
```

I suppose that:

$x_1=v$

$x_2=P_{sc}$

$x_3=n_f$

$x_4=x'_1$

I expect to find a current pulse like figure 1 but I get a exponential solution.

[image: Figure 1]

What is wrong in this code and can you suggest me how i can solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp! Could you elaborate a bit on the physics of your model? Is "deltat" a problem parameter, or does that refer to a time step?

Comment: Hi. deltat is a time step. And in the model the exponential factor for x'3 is e^((t/deltat)^2))

Comment: Having the time step for a numerical method inside your ODE system makes no sense; that information is for the discrete formulation only.

Answer (score 5):

You can use MATLAB's `ode45`, please refer to the first example here: [Solve nonstiff differential equations; low order method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode23.html).

Here I use $y$ instead of $x$. If you don't know how to write a $\mathtt{func.m}$ script and save it in your path, you can use function handle as well, in your case:

```
% output of function handle in vector form
rigid = @(t,y)[x(4); -x(2)+x(3);  ??? ; ???];
options = odeset('RelTol',1e-6,'AbsTol',[1e-6 1e-6 1e-6 1e-6]);
[t,y] = ode45(rigid,[0 T],[y10 y20 y30 y40],options);
```

`???` is left for you to fill up, you can tweak the `options` if you read the document of the link above, `y10` through `y40` are the initial values. Lastly `J = y(:,1).*y(:,3)` then [plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) $J$ against $t$.

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for your assistance. I don´t have initial values in my problem. it is possible avoid this initial conditions?. or I have to deduce them.

Comment: @user4671 You have to have initial condition, initial condition means what the system is like when you start your timer.

Comment: Depending on the argument to the exponential, `ode45` may be inappropriate due to stiffness, and replaced with `ode15s`.

Comment: The matlab code that i wrote for this problem is the next: i´ve included some constants for simulation purpouses:

Comment: tr=50e-12;%Recombination lifetime
n0=1%e11;%Density carriers 
tc=2e-12%Trapping time
ts=30e-15;%scattering time
m=0.067*9.11e-31;%mass LT-GaAs
ev=8.854e-12;%vaccum 
n=900;%geometrical factor
q=1.6e-19%electron 
de=50e-15%deltat 
timeRange=[0 0.1e-12]; initialConditionVector=[0;1e-15;1e-15;1e-15];
[t,x]=ode45(@xprime,timeRange,initialConditionVector);
figure(1),plot(t,x(:,1))
J=q*x(:,3).*x(:,1);
figure(2),plot(t,J)
function f=xprime(t,x)
    f=[x(4);-(x(2)/tr)+(x(3)*q*x(1));-(x(3)/tc)+(n0*(exp((t/de)^2)));-((1/ts)*x(4))-(((x(3)*q^2)/m*ev)*x(1)/n)+(q*x(2)/(m*n*ev*tr))];
end
end

Comment: With this code I did not found the solution that I hope. What is wrong?

Comment: @user4671: If possible, you should nondimensionalize your equations so that the rescaled state variables and time variable are roughly 1 over the new time interval of interest.

Comment: @GeoffOxberry I don't understand your answer. can you help me explain it?

Comment: @ShuhaoCao I already do it. can you help me?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondimensionalization

Comment: The line n0=1%e11;         % Density of free carriers (Rqcordar quq qs 1q17 cm-3) is very peculiar. Is n0 supposed to be 1 or 1e11?

Comment: @BillGreene Yes it is 1e11